# How do I rewrite the following for a resume?

Tags: resume

I did a study on Network File System in the course Operating Systems. I also implemented NFS server and NFS client on Ubuntu. I also wrote a project report on it.

I want to write above in a resume. I didn't do any new research. But I wrote a report on it.
I just can't figure out a way to write in a resume. I don't want others to get the wrong idea, as I didn't do any research.

P.S. I am a fresher. It was a course project.

Comment: If you're writing a resume for a programming position, the fact that you implemented an NFS server and client is *way* more interesting than the fact that you wrote a report.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're focusing on the wrong angle. Think about it this way: why would a potential employer care that you wrote a report? What skill set does it show you have? What does it prove you could do again?

So think about the report:

- Why did you write the report? For whom? Boss, peers, IT, management,
  accounting? What are they going to do with the report when it's done?
- Was it just stating the facts of what NFS can do, or were you
  analyzing pros and cons of installation, or comparing it to some
  other system?
- What were the sources of the report? Did you pull information from
  many different sources and create a new reference document for your
  department, or did you just copy what you learned in the course?

Once you figure that out, it will be much easier to write it as a résumé bullet. ("Analyzed NFS system so that IT Department could justify purchase requisition for next year's budget," for example.)

Answer (score 6):

As a former employer I agree that most employers don't care about reports that you might have written. You need to stress knowledge and experience in a resume.  If you have no experience (that the company can use) the best you might be able to do is show knowledge in a way that someone might ask you a question in an interview.

And unless the company you are sending the resume to is using Umbuntu then they won't really care. As I recall "implementing NFS" in that environment isn't that hard so I'm not sure whether an employer would even be impressed if you do find a way to include it.

Many companies are now using software to scan through the resumes and applications they get. You need to write your resume to (hopefully) reflect the keywords that reflect the job skills the company wants. What (if anything) in your report can save the company money?

Since this is a writing forum then think of your resume as your 30 second commercial. Companies want to reduce costs and make/keep their customers (other employees) happy. If you can't think of a way to do either with your report than I would suggest you leave it out and hope that maybe you can work it into an answer to a question during the interview.

BTW, can you fix an NFS problem in the mentioned environment? Think. If you put it on a hundred systems and it goes bad on the V.P.'s desktop machine you better be able to diagnose and resolve the issue or your future boss will be filling your job...again.